# DNN 9.13.01 on Windows Server 2019 throws null reference exception when installing extension

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dotnetnuke-9

I'm in the process of exploring replacing my current blogging solution with DNN but installing the 2sxcApp_Blog_6.1.0.zip extension on a fresh install of DNN 9.13.01 fails.

1. Drag zip file to loading zone on web page
2. I get "Zip File Upload Failed"
3. Clicking on "View Error Log" displays:

   An unknown error has occured. Please check your installation zip file and try again.

   Common issues with bad installation files:

   - Zip file size is too large, check your IIS settings for max upload file size.
   - Missing resources in the zip file.
   - Invalid files in the package.
   - File extension is not .zip.
   - Check that you are logged in.
4. Looking at the network traffic in the dev tools shows a **500 response** from `/dnn/API/PersonaBar/Extensions/ParsePackage`.
5. The preview pane for /dnn/API/PersonaBar/Extensions/ParsePackage shows the common ASP.Net error page, "Object not set to an instance of an object."
   Stack trace:

   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Util.IsFileValid(InstallFile file, String packageWhiteList) +105
   DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.InstallerInfo.<get_HasValidFiles>b__6_0(InstallFile file) +18
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +169
   DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.InstallerInfo.get_HasValidFiles() +137
   Dnn.PersonaBar.Extensions.Components.InstallController.ParsePackage(PortalSettings portalSettings, UserInfo user, String filePath, Stream stream) +477
   Dnn.PersonaBar.Extensions.Services.<>c__DisplayClass42_1.b__1(Object state) +46
   System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(Action action) +108

This is running on Windows Server 2019 and SQL Server 2019.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that you state what version of the 2sxc module you have installed, but I think that might be the problem and the answer. 2sxc Apps get installed within 2sxc and maybe you do not have 2sxc installed yet?

Here are the detailed steps and prerequisites for install the 2sxc Blog app.
https://azing.org/2sxc/r/vgApEx0X

And here is where you would download the installer for the 2sxc module. This is what you install first, in the usual way, in DNN (Settings/Extensions, Install Extension button).
https://github.com/2sic/2sxc

So, if I am wrong and you did have 2sxc installed, what version is it?